# CentOS 7 OSM Tile Server - PostgreSQL install conflict error

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

We just got a new CentOS 7 VM spun up and started setting up our server for an OSM tile server. Attempting to install and configure PostgreSQL with the following command:

```
 yum install postgresql94-server postgresql94-devel postgis2_94 postgis2_94-docs postgis2_94-utils pgrouting_94
```

I receive the following Transaction check error:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib/liblwgeom.so from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer.control from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer.sql from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer_data_us.control from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/address_standardizer_data_us.sql from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis.control from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_sfcgal.control from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder.control from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder.sql from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
  file /usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension/postgis_topology.control from install of postgis24_94-2.4.6-4.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64
```

What am I missing here? I understand the errors are stating there is a conflict between two version of postgis **24** and **22** but how would I go about remedying the conflict?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a programming question. Try https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using more recent version of PostgreSQL since the support for 9.4 will end in next year.

> The PostgreSQL community will stop releasing updates for the 9.4.X release series in February 2020. Users are encouraged to update to a newer release branch soon.

Well, since you seem to have the `postgis22_94-2.2.7-1.rhel7.x86_64` installed and you want to use a different version, I'd suggest removing the undesired version before installing the new one.

Also, if I remember correctly different major versions of PostgreSQL are actually packaged in a way that let's installing e.g 10 and 9.6 on the same machine without conflicts (since the binaries will reside in different directories).

Comment: You remember correctly - the binaries are installed side-by-side. The second install will use the next available port number. So the first installed version will use 5432, the second 5433 and so on.